# Comparing objects within a set

Tags: java, hash, set

Right now I have this Java code

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

public class Dummy {

    private String value;

    public Dummy(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public boolean equals(final Object that) {
        return that instanceof Dummy && Objects.equals(value, ((Dummy) that).value);
    }

    public int hashcode() {
        return Objects.hash(value);
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final Set<Dummy> dummies = new HashSet<>();
        dummies.add(new Dummy("toto"));
        System.out.println(dummies.contains(new Dummy("toto")));
    }
}
```

The output is "false", and I'm supposed to change it to "true" by changing only one character, but I have absolutely no idea how to do that... Any ideas? Thanks. :)

Comment: your hashcode and equals are lazy implemented...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

hashcode() is not a Object's method but hashCode() is.

```
 public int hashcode() {
         return Objects.hash(value);
   }
```

should be

```
public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(value);
    }
```

Comment: You might want to add that "adding @Override" would to both methods would reveal that little dirty "trick" immediately.

Comment: you are right but it is more than one character (the rule of the game ;-) )

Comment: You answered the "puzzle" part. So, that gives an "OK answer". A great answer tries to open up "more perspective"; for example by adding how using @Override makes that little trick impossible - in other words: how it prevents you from making such stupid mistakes in the real world. Now it is your choice if you are happy with an "OK answer", or if you strive for more than that. ;-)

Comment: You are totally right . I though at the same thing that you : securing with the annotation :) Just I answered only to the question  at the moment :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had lots of objects who all need a equals and hash method. I have used [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/)  to reduce the work and code.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class JsonPictureStuff {
    private String type;
    private String url;
    private String width;
    private String height;
}
```

The annotations instruct lombok to add the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

your set is not working because you are implementing equals and hashcode in a not proper way...

1. specially because you are not even considering the string field
2. you are avoiding the annotation Override that will hint you about wrongly named methods like **hashcode** and **hashCode**

you can do something like

```
   @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((value == null) ? 0 : value.hashCode());
    return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Dummy  other = (Dummy ) obj;
    if (value == null) {
        if (other.value != null)
        return false;
    } else if (!value.equals(other.value))
        return false;
    return true;
    }
```

in ide like eclipse you can do right click and auto generate those methods so you can save the implementation

Comment: Doesn't really answer. He has a puzzle there, and the whole point of the puzzle is the joke that it is *hashcode*, not *hash**C**ode*! He asked about the **one** character to change to fix the program!